# Sift descriptor at particular pixel

Tags: matlab, vlfeat

I want to find the sift descriptor at a co-ordinate ( x ,y ) in the image with a patch size of 5X5 neighbour with the co-ordinate in the middle.

The intention behind it is to analyse the orientation values that I get on that co-ordinate for further processing.

Is there any method in matlab that would allow me to do this ?

I have tried to understand [vl_dsift](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/dsift.html) which would give me sift descriptor at every point and maybe use it for just the co-ordinate that I want but could not understand how to use it ...

Could someone help me with it or suggest any better alternative out there ?

Comment: have you tried reproducing the example given on the vl_dsift website? If so, where do you get stuck?

Comment: I am unable to understand how will I get the orientation values for a 5X5 window.... something like this http://i49.tinypic.com/wuqww7.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The MATLAB command vl_sift (and the command line utility) can bypass
>   the detector and compute the descriptor on custom frames using the
>   Frames option.
>
> For instance, we can compute the descriptor of a SIFT frame centered
>   at position (100,100), of scale 10 and orientation -pi/8 by
>
> ```
> fc = [100;100;10;-pi/8] ;
> [f,d] = vl_sift(I,'frames',fc) ;
> ```
>
> Multiple frames fc may be specified as well. In this case they are
>   re-ordered by increasing scale. The Orientations option instructs the
>   program to use the custom position and scale but to compute the
>   keypoint orientations, as in
>
> ```
> fc = [100;100;10;0] ;
> [f,d] = vl_sift(I,'frames',fc,'orientations') ;
> ```
>
> Notice that, depending on the local appearance, a keypoint may have
>   multiple orientations. Moreover, a keypoint computed on a constant
>   image region (such as a one pixel region) has no orientations!

checkout http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/sift.html . vl_feat is really really neat, and very easy to use, even easier to install.